# Confused about different GSA XML feed formats

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, salesforce, google-search-appliance

On this page https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/64/feedsguide it talks about XML input feeds starting with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE gsafeed PUBLIC "-//Google//DTD GSA Feeds//EN" "">
<gsafeed>
    <header>
        <datasource>sample_feed</datasource>
        <feedtype>full</feedtype>
    </header>
    <group>
        <record url="http://www.localhost.test.com/" action="add" mimetype="text/html">
            <content><![CDATA[ ...
    ...etc...
```

But oddly in the SalesForce connector, the OUTPUT of the SOAP XSLT (which I believe is then sent to Google) looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<documents>
  <document>
    <spiheaders>
      <spiheader name="DEFAULT_MIMETYPE">text/html</spiheader>
      <spiheader name="PROPNAME_ACTION">add</spiheader>
      <spiheader name="PROPNAME_CONTENTURL">https://cs2.salesforce.com/500i0000002gIysAAE</spiheader>
      <spiheader name="PROPNAME_DISPLAYURL">https://cs2.salesforce.com/500i0000002gIysAAE</spiheader>
      <spiheader name="PROPNAME_DOCID">500i0000002gIysAAE</spiheader>
      <spiheader name="PROPNAME_ISPUBLIC">true</spiheader>
      <spiheader name="PROPNAME_MIMETYPE">text/html</spiheader>
      <spiheader name="PROPNAME_SEARCHURL"/>
      <spiheader name="PROPNAME_SECURITYTOKEN"/>
    </spiheaders>
    <metadata>
      <meta name="CaseNumber">00001000</meta>
    </metadata>
    <content encoding="none"><![CDATA[
        ...
...etc...
```

I believe SaleForce initially returns SOAP XML with its own fields, but then the connector applies the XSLT of your choice to convert it into XML destined for the Google Appliance.

So is the `<gsafeed>` just a newer dialect of GSA over some older `<documents>` dialect?

Note: I did search on google, but I keep finding the SalesForce specific doc.  And search terms like "documents" aren't very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is correct. The feed XML that gets sent to the GSA contains records. There will be one record entry per document to be fed.

Typically when you're writing a custom connector you build a document list containing the document metadata (and content if it's a content feed), pass it to the Connector Manager and it converts it to a feed and sends it to the GSA. The second piece of XML you included looks like an XML representation of such a document list.

So to answer your question, No - gsafeed is not a newer dialect of GSA overs some older documents dialect.

Take a look at the [Connector Developers Guide](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/connectors/200/connector_dev/cdg_about) if you want more detail.

Comment: OK so there's 2 completely different XML formats for every doc, that seems wasteful, seems like they'd pick one or the other. I appreciate your link to the API doc but haven't found url that describes the <documents> XML format (hard to search since it uses common words), do you happen to know that url? Instead of using a JAVA API to build my docs, I'm using XSLT from another XML format. If I have an arbitrary XML format and XSL, I could translate it into either format, but seems like I'd need to inject it into different spots depending on the format I choose. Still a bit confused, but thx.

Comment: @MarkBennett, reading between the lines you're using the google salesforce connector. I haven't had a lot of exposure to that particular connector but have you tried [this document](http://google-enterprise-connector-salesforce.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/projects/salesforce/docs/salesforce_connector.html#Configurereqxslt)?